# Prestashop edit header css

Tags: css, header, prestashop

Prestashop 1.7.5.0 / custom theme
I would like to change header-top class with css. Tried to change `theme.css` but nothing happened when I added this:

```
#header .header-top {
    margin-left: 200px;
    margin-right: 200px;
    margin-top: 20px; }
```

What should it look like?

Answer (score 0):

You have to clear Prestashop cache to see your changes